# Is this the right way to think about accelerated observers?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, observers

$c=1$

I'm trying to think of a way to understand the change of coordinates from an observer at rest to an accelerated one. Clearly, a single Lorentz transformation with $v=v(t)$ is not the right way to go about it (how do you even invert the relations?), so I've come up with an iterative scheme to compute the transformation of time and space.

Let $\mathrm{T}$ be the time elapsed at the system which is at rest. Let $x$ be the starting point of the accelerated observer. Let's assume that the acceleration $a$ is constant and the starting velocity is equal to $0$.

Suppose that the elapsed time is divided into $N$ small intervals $\Delta t$, with $\Delta t = \mathrm{T}/N$. We can compute the transformed coordinates $x(i)$ and $t(i)$ at each step by performing a Lorentz transformation of the previous step. This way
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  T(i) & = & i\Delta t \\
  & & \\
  t'(i) & = & \gamma[v(i-1)][t(i-1) - v(i-1)x(i-1)] \\
  & & \\
  x'(i) & = & \gamma[v(i-1)][x(i-1)-v(i-1)t(i-1)] \\
  & & \\
  v(i) & = & \dfrac{v(i-2)-v(i-1)}{1-v(i-1)v(i-2)}
\end{array}
$$

with $x'(0)=x$, $t'(0) = 0$, $t'(1) = \Delta t$, $v(0)=0$, $v(1)=a\Delta t$. I planned to increase the $N$ while keeping $\mathrm{T}$ constant, but I'd like to be sure if this is the right thing to do. At some point I thought to make $v(i) = ia\Delta t$, but that seemed inconsistent.

Comment: [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) can be used to describe uniform acceleration.

Comment: @Ghoster There are some things about those coordinates which I can't wrap my head around. Why don't they allow to describe the origin of space coordinates for the moving observer? Since $x=0$ implies that $X=T=0$ does that mean that $x=0$ can only be described when the moving observer passes through the one at rest?